# Python csv.DictWriter not writing Dictory to writerow method

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Python - 3.8

I am trying to write a csv file from a list of dictionary. I followed the official [website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) example. writer is able to write headers. But it is not writing the rows from dictionary that i loops from the list.

```
        csv_path = "/home/tmp/file.csv"
        with open(csv_path, 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["RequestTimestamp", "MerchantId", "MerchantName", "ChannelName",
                                                         "MerchantUSN", "BatchNumber", "UniqueId", "TransactionId", "InvoiceId",
                                                         "ReferenceTimestamp", "CustomerName", "AccountHolder", "PaymentType",
                                                         "Currency", "Debit", "Credit", "SettledAmount", "Result", "bankResult", "ReconStatus"])
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in recons:
                result_dict = utils.data_formatter_handler(data)
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Can you add `print(data)` before `writer.writerow(data)` to ensure that data is present and computed & returned correctly by `utils.data_formatter_handler`?

Comment: Could you post the `result_dict`

Comment: show what `recons` looks like. What is `utils.data_formatter_handler`. Also, probably you want to write `result_dict`, not `data`.

Comment: if i use result_dict it throws no keys error, i am passing a dictornary object(data)

Comment: I meant to post, the contents of result and also data, in the question

Comment: if `data` is dict as expected, why do you create result_dict? If there is some error when you use result_dict, there is probably missing key. Still, you need to give us more info as I advised in my previous comment.

Comment: if there is no error then pls try by just closing the file. Actually with open doesn't need to close, it automatically does but one day I faced the same issue and at last, I tried this and it worked.